# Angular HTML code to format and print a number as positive (without minus sign)

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I have a number that can be positive or negative value. I want to always print it as negative. Is there a way to format it in Angular 2 html code? I know how to do it in typescript/javascript. But, wondering if I can just format in Angular HTML code directly

Comment: Create a custom pipe with this transform function `return -Math.abs(num)`

Answer (score 7):

A fast way to get the negative of a number is:

```
-Math.abs(num);
```

---

Angular uses pipes to transform the data rendered in the templates.
Create a custom pipe:

if you use angular-cli
`ng g pipe minus`

```
@Pipe({name: 'minus'})

export class MinusPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(num: number, args?: any): any {
    return -Math.abs(num);
  }
}
```

In your template:

```
{{ myNumber | minus }}
```

Answer (score 5):

Old question but still actual. As an alternative to creating new pipes you can make global objects such as 'Math' available in your template.

Define in your controller something like:

```
public myMath = Math;
```

Now you can use it in your html template:

```
{{myMath.abs(the_number)}}
```

Comment: Your way was the only way that worked in Angular 10 using ionic.  The pipes did not work for some reason.  Thank you!

Comment: This definitely works, but it isn't a great solution. Having the binding hooked up directly to a method causes angular to recalculate this whenever _anything_ on the screen changes. Using a pipe let's angular intelligently know when to update it instead of Angular having to re-run the method every time _in case_ something changed.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a pipe. Here is one:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'negativeNumber'})

export class NumberFormatPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: number): number { 
      return Math.abs(value)*(-1);
    }
}
```

Uses in html like this

```
<div>{{somevalue | negativeNumber}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution in my case was putting minus behind number, but filtering positive numbers was a problem if have positive numbers

```
{{ (num >= 0 ? num : -num) }}
```

Comment: Though this answer would work (after switching the minus to the left side in order to match the goal to get a negative number) I would advice against it and suggest using -Math.abs(num) as others answered since this way it is immediately obvious what you are doing. For example you would catch the missplaced minus.